# How to make ItemSearch request for Japanese word "並行輸入" using Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-product-advertising-api

I am stuck in making ItemSearch request for the keyword "並行輸入" using Amazon Product Advertising API.

When we put this word in [amazon.co.jp](http://www.amazon.co.jp), it gives me list of products. However, when I put request through API, it returns no results saying **"AWS.ECommerceService.NoExactMatches"**.

I convert the above word to unicode and tried, but had no luck.

See my request to amazon.co.jp.

```
GET http://ecs.amazonaws.jp/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=MyAccessKey&AssociateTag=myTag&Keywords=%26%2320006%3B%26%2334892%3B%26%2336664%3B%26%2320837%3B&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=OfferFull%2CMedium%2CItemAttributes&SearchIndex=Grocery&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2013-05-22T05%3A48%3A32Z&Signature=mySignature HTTP/1.1
```

---

Your prompt response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get results from Amazon Products API for your search keywords:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.jp/onca/xml?
AWSAccessKeyId=key
&AssociateTag=tag
&Keywords=%E4%B8%A6%E8%A1%8C%E8%BC%B8%E5%85%A5
&Operation=ItemSearch
&SearchIndex=Grocery
&Timestamp=timestamp
&Signature=signature
```

Keywords are encoded in UTF-8.
I used Amazon Signed Requests Helper to sign the request. There I used Japanese keywords not transforming them into Unicode. The tool encoded them for me.